# Base class parameter vs pure virtual function for customizable constant

Tags: c++

Say I have some base class, and all instances of that class have some constant property (which is private to the class). The value of that property is determined by the derived class. For each derived class, it could either be intrinsic or dependent on the constructor parameters.

Is it preferable to express this customizable property as a parameter to the base class constructor, or as a pure virtual method? Is there a strong reason to prefer one over the other?

For a concrete picture of the two options I'm thinking about:

```
// Option with the constructor param. Call it a bool for simplicity.
class BaseClass {
  public:
    BaseClass(bool property) : property_(property) {}
    ...
  private:
    GetProperty() { return property_; }

    const bool property_;
}
class DerivedClassOne : public BaseClass {
  public:
    DerivedClassOne() : BaseClass(false) {}
}
class DerivedClassTwo : public BaseClass {
  public:
    DerivedClassTwo(int some_param) : BaseClass(some_param > 0) {}
}
```

Versus:

```
// Option with the pure virtual method.
class BaseClass {
  private:
    virtual GetProperty() = 0;
}
class DerivedClassOne : public BaseClass {
  private:
    GetProperty() override { return false; }
}
class DerivedClassTwo : public BaseClass {
  public:
    DerivedClassTwo(int some_param) : some_param_(some_param) {}
  private:
    GetProperty() override { return some_param > 0; }

    const int some_param_;
}
```

Am I just splitting hairs here?

Comment: You may just be splitting hairs but in these cases that's when I like to think about efficiency. With virtual methods you are adding 2 additional pointers and a function call just to get that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would slightly prefer the 1st method.

The virtual function call probably cant be optimized away - at least not if called via a pointer to the class. The constant can be used directly and even if you use the get function, its call can probably be optimized by the compiler.

Also, there is more code to read in the virtual function version.